# BITMAPV5HEADER getting RGBA keep A at 255

Tags: winapi, gdi, bitblt

I am obtaining a byte array of a screenshot by the following, this is done in ctypes, there is no issues with the ctypes, if I gave this a ctypes tag the ctypes folks would be confused, so I simplified out all the error checking etc to show you the procedure.

```
CreateDC('DISPLAY', null, null, null);

nWidth = GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, HORZRES); // 1280 // numbers are always divisilbe by 4
nHeight = GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, ostypes.CONST.VERTRES); // 1024
nBPP = GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, BITSPIXEL); // 32

hdcMemoryDC = ostypes.API('CreateCompatibleDC')(hdcScreen);

bmi = BITMAPV5HEADER();
bmi.bV5Size = BITMAPV5HEADER.size;
bmi.bV5Width = nWidth;
bmi.bV5Height = -1 * nHeight; // top-down
bmi.bV5Planes = 1;
bmi.bV5BitCount = nBPP;
bmi.bV5Compression = BI_BITFIELDS;
bmi.bV5RedMask = 0xff;
bmi.bV5GreenMask = 0xff00;
bmi.bV5BlueMask = 0xff0000;
bmi.bV5AlphaMask = 0xff000000;

cBmi = ctypes.cast(bmi.address(), BITMAPINFO.ptr);
pixelBuffer = BYTE.ptr();
hbmp = CreateDIBSection(hdcScreen, cBmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, pixelBuffer.address(), null, 0); 

SelectObject(hdcMemoryDC, hbmp);

BitBlt(hdcMemoryDC, 0,0, nWidth, nHeight, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

byteArr = ctypes.cast(pixelBuffer, BYTE.array(arrLen).ptr).contents;
```

So with the above flags I get a BGRA byteArr which looks like this:

```
array(5242880)([240, 200, 105, 255, ..... ])
```

So the B is 240, G is 200, R is 105, and A is 255.

I want to get this into a RGBA form (it's important it's done on the C side for ctypes performance reasons).

So now we can successfully get it into RGBA form HOWEVER the A becomes 0, by using these masks:

```
bmi.bV5RedMask = 0xff0000;
bmi.bV5GreenMask = 0xff00;
bmi.bV5BlueMask = 0xff;
bmi.bV5AlphaMask = 0xff000000; // we also tried 0x00000000
```

This now gives us:

```
array(5242880)([105, 200, 240, 0, ..... ])
```

So the issue is the A value is going to 0, how can I keep this RGBA format, but keep the A value at 255.

Answer (score 1):

BitBlt, like nearly all GDI functions, doesn't preserve the alpha values.

If you're blitting from the screen, then all the alphas are 255--the screen doesn't have holes of transparency.  So you can just set the alphas yourself after doing the blit.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you apply alpha to a screen capture and want to use the GDI `AlphaBlend()` function to do transparency, you will need to premultiply the alpha values as well.

Comment: Since all the alphas are 255, the colors are effectively already pre-multiplied by the alpha.

Comment: I meant with the new alpha values that he wants to apply, since that's how I read your answer =P But right, if he just wants to blend on top of this image as is, it doesn't need any changes.

Comment: Thanks AdrianMcCarthy adn @andlabs I can't do go through and set the to 255 for large images on the non-c side part of the js-ctypes it takes up to 2.5s which is a long delay. That's why im trying hard to make the C set it to 255. Because then I just `memcpy` the byte array to a javascript ArrayBuffer and boom 4ms I got my image. The driving me nuts part was if I have it in BGRA, then A is 255, any other order of the masks and the A value goes o 0, I can't make it stay 255, so that's my issue.

Comment: You can't make it stay 255 because BitBlt doesn't support it.  The fact that you got 255 with any combination is dumb luck.  You'll have to set the alphas to 255 yourself.  You can do it in the C code, but BitBlt won't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks very much @AdrianMcCarthy is there a function I can use of winapi that will go through array and set it to something i tell it?

Comment: Oh is there a method with SetICMMode (I found it linked from SetDIBits) to make that A come out to be 255? Ah or maybe _swab i just found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273384%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: Just write a loop to set the alphas after the blit.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMcCarthy but from ctypes I can't write a loop, i have to use exported functions from libraries. I can create my own library but that will require native file signing every 6 weeks (for security reasons with firefox addons) which is a headache.

Comment: But what I dont understand is if BitBlt doesnt preserve alpha values shouldn't i be able to just get a RGB array out? I can't seem to get a 3 byte arr, only 4 bytes which means it has to include A.

Comment: You can get an RGB array.  You'd have to set the number of bits per pixel (`bmi.bV5BitCount`) to 24 instead of the 32 you're using now.  (You also have to take care that each row of the bitmap is aligned to a 4-byte boundary, which means there might be a small number of bytes of padding between each row.)  Just because your screen is set to use 4 bytes per pixel does not mean those extra bits are treated as alphas or that they have any particular value.