# How to put BGRA array into canvas without re-ordering

Tags: javascript, canvas, firefox-addon

I have a BGRA array and need to draw it to a canvas.

Currently i was doing it like this:

```
var aVal = returnedFromChromeWorker;
var can = doc.createElementNS(NS_HTML, 'canvas');
can.width = aVal.width;
can.height = aVal.height;
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.putImageData(aVal, 0, 0);

doc.documentElement.appendChild(can);
```

Is there some way to get a BGRA array onto the canvas? I was exploring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/imgIEncoder

I can't re-order the array because my goal is to take screenshots and for large screens even just 1280x1024, it takes 2.3s to go through and re-order it all.

I tried re-ordering on the ctypes side but it's giving me quirky issues:  0, making the whole image invisible >_< lol [BITMAPV5HEADER getting RGBA keep A at 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083256/bitmapv5header-getting-rgba-keep-a-at-255)

Comment: Can include `array` containing `rgba` values at Question ?

Comment: Hi @guest271314 i fixed the title i meant BGRA

Comment: @guest271314 it's the byte-order for red-green-red-alpha component, each 1 byte, stored in an Uint32.

Comment: Wait until the [SIMD API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SIMD) is mature, then play with `int8x16` and `shuffle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to put BGRA array into canvas without re-ordering

**There is none.**

Reorganize the byte-order is necessary as canvas can only hold data in RGBA format (little-endian, ie. ABGR in the buffer). Here is one way to do this:

You could add an extra step for your worker to deal with the reordering. Create a `DataView` for the raw byte buffer (ArrayBuffer), then iterate each Uint32 value.

Below a Uint32 is read as little-endian. This is because in this case that format is easier to swap around as we only need to right-shift BGR and put A back in front. If your original buffer is in big-endian you will of course need to read it as big-endian and set back as little-endian (getUint32(pos, false)):

### Example

```js
var uint32 = new Uint32Array(1), pos = 0;  // create some dummy data
var view = new DataView(uint32.buffer);    // create DataView for byte-buffer
var pos = 0;                               // byte-position (we'll skip 4 bytes each time)

// dummy data in BGRA format
uint32[0] = 0x7722ddff; // magenta-ish in BGRA format
document.write("BGRA: 0x" + (uint32[0]).toString(16) +  "<br>");

// --- Iterate buffer, for each: ---
var v = view.getUint32(pos, true); // BGRA -> RGBA, read as little-endian
var n = (v >>> 8) | (v << 24);     // rotate - move A from last to first position
view.setUint32(pos, n, true);      // set back
pos += 4;                          // do this when inside the loop

// result
document.write("ABGR: 0x" + (uint32[0]>>>0).toString(16));
```

**Update** If the byte-order (endian-wise) is the same in both end you can skip the `DataView` and use `Uint32Array` directly which will speed things up a tad as well:

```
var uint32 = new Uint32Array(1), pos = 0;  // create some dummy data

// inside loop:
var v = uint32[pos];
uint32[pos++] = (v >>> 8) | (v << 24);  // pos index is now per uint32
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ken! Your method was really fast!! Mine was taking such a long time because I think I was repeatedly dereferencing. Thanks again you're like the ImageData expert! :D

Comment: @Noitidart no problem! :D I forgot to state that if your incoming data is in little-endian already you can just use Uint32Array instead of DataView - that will make it slightly faster.

Comment: Ah it sped it up 50ms thank you!!! :) This is  a diff when its down from 150ms :)